# Heroku logs: "missing script:start" ,even it is in :(

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, web-deployment, package.json

I am trying to deploy a simple node.js app to heroku but it keeps telling me that  "missing script: start" even after adding it in the package.json
my packacge.json looks like:-

```
    {
  "name": "deploy_demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "keywords": [
    "util",
    "functional",
    "server",
    "client",
    "browser"
  ],
  "author": "Babar",
  "contributors": [],
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^2.5.2",
    "express": "^4.14.0"
  },
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
     "start": "node main.js"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

my code for my entry point:
[main.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4a56O.png)

Heroku logs:
[heroku logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NG99.png)

**Note: This app is working fine in localhost server**
please help me out,i am new in node.js,thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `process.env.PORT` to set the port in any Node.js Heroku app.

Also be sure that the code you're running on `localhost` is the same that's running on your Heroku app.

Answer (score 2):

You can't listen on a custom port on Heroku, you have to use process.env.PORT so that they can set it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have made sure its in `package.json` like,

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node main.js"
}
```

..and you could try adding a [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) with,

```
web: npm start
```

Other than that, if its only working locally for you, also make sure you commit and push to Heroku, something like `git push heroku master`.

Aside: by the way, the convection is to name your start point like `server.js`

Answer (score 1):

Try this on

```
"scripts":{
"start":"node ."
```

}

and also use PORT in env